# Elimine los recursos que bloquean el renderizado

Tags: wordpress

Hola amigos alguno sabe como podria reducir esta metrica en wordpress [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: al pareser las tienes estaticas y las solicitud se hace a tu web! colocalas por cdn! asi sera un server externo el que responda a la solicitud!

Comment: He analizado la carga de tu web en el navegador y me ha dado unos valores de TTFB de más de 500ms (entre 600 y 800ms). Eso es excesivo y podría reflejar que los recursos de tu servidor son limitados o tienes cuello de botella en CPU o disco. Eso es el tiempo hasta que llega el primer octeto de datos al navegador desde que se envían las cabeceras. Luego la descarga es más o menos rápida (<20ms). Viendo que usas el CDN cloudflare puedo imaginarme que el problema está en que tu servidor podría tener problemas de ancho de banda de subida y/o no aprovechar las capacidades de caché del CDN.

Comment: Para eso último te recomiendo hacer uso de algún complemento como [W3 Total Cache](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/). Enviando cabeceras al CDN indicando que ciertos recursos son estáticos, tienen un tiempo de expiración algo o que no han sido modificados reducirás la carga de tu servidor real y podrás mejorar los tiempos de respuesta general. ¿Qué conexión de subida tienes en tu servidor? ¿Es una conexión casera (como ADSL, fibra óptica, cable, etc) o una profesional (alojamiento compartido o decidado, VPS o servidor dedicado, etc)?

Comment: @OscarGarcia Gracias por tu respuesta, amigo, te cuento que pago el servidor de CloudWays ellos son como un puente para armar rápido los server dedicados de digital ocean tengo un paquete de 20$ con estas caracteristicas

2 GB
50GB SSD
2tb Transfer
1 Core Processador

Otra cosa que me he dado cuenta es que los resultados van variando cada cierto tiempo que hago las peticiones en el lightroom o pagespeed aveces me da valores en verde otras en naranja y otras en rojas entonces no entiendo xD

Comment: @OscarGarcia haré lo del W3 Total Cache muchas gracias !

Comment: Todo apunta a cuello de botella en tu VPS. Para determinar si te falta CPU, ¿Podrías ejecutar la instrucción `top` durante la ejecución de las pruebas? Al tener el servidor web y la base de datos en una máquina con un único núcleo van a pelear por su uso ambos procesos. Si el uso de CPU de mantiene cerca del 100% durante la prueba y la carga de CPU sube bastante por encima de 2, te indicará que un único núcleo es insuficiente. Comparte una captura de pantalla del `top` durante las pruebas para poder ayudarte a interpretar lo que muestra.

Comment: Por cierto, ese VPS me parece excesivamente caro. En [OVHcloud](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/OVH) tienes por unos 16€ (con impuestos incluidos) 4 vCore con 8 GB, 160 GB SSD NVMe y ancho de banda de 1 Gb/s (con tráfico ilimitado) https://www.ovhcloud.com/es-es/vps/